# How To Send Cookies To A Website Through Laravel Panel Using PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, php-curl, amember

I have built a website `abcd.com` where I want to sell online products. It is connected with amember pro.

Now I have created a panel in Laravel, `panel.abcd.com` where I set up the products url and cookies.

Now if I update or put cookies on `panel.abcd.com`I want that cookies to redirect on `abcd.com` site so that user do not need to log in to use my product. I want to redirect that cookies to my abcd.com/product.

I am able to redirect the site. But the cookies is not redirecting.

```
<?php `
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','newuser','password','mark12');
if(isset($_GET['tool'])){
 echo $tool=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['tool']);
$res=mysqli_query($con,"select domain from extension_tools where tool_name='$tool'");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($count>0){
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
 $domain=$row['domain'];
header('location:'.$domain);
die();
}

}


?>
```

That is the code I used to redirect to the product site in my amember setup.

and It's working but the cookies is not redirecting in that product site. Please help me to redirect the cookies also. Thank you.

Comment: _"but the cookies is not loading"_ - That code doesn't have anything to do with cookies. The question is very unclear, tbh. Please edit your question to include _all_ relevant code (and make sure you format it by using proper indention) and write a more detailed example you expect the code to do and what currently happens. Be as specific as possible. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also take time to go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which was suggested to you when you joined (and you still haven't done)

Comment: Guzzle w/ CookieJar

Comment: Please check. Help me sir. I am currently in depression whenever I think about this problem.